# JS ReferenceError: getActivityTables is not defined at onload

Tags: javascript, html

Why is getActivityTables() not defined? The script is properly linked, and the function name is the same in the html as well as js file.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Fitnessapp</title>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="getActivityTables()">    
    <div id="" class="container">
        <div class="activityDiv">
            <h1>Running Activities</h1>
            <table id="runningActivity-table" class="table">
            </table>
        </div>                
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS (scripts.js):

```
function getActivityTables() {
    console.log("test");
    // Get runningActivity-table
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function () {
        let response;
        let responseString = xhttp.responseText;
        response = JSON.parse(responseString);
        console.log(response);

        let table = document.getElementById("runningActivity-table");
        let row, cell;
        let header = table.createTHead();
        row = header.insertRow(0);
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = "ID";
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = "Date";
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = "Duration";
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = "Distance";
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.innerHTML = "Description";

        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            row = table.insertRow();
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.textContent = response[i].id;
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.textContent = response[i].dateOfCreation;
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.textContent = response[i].durationInMinutes;
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.textContent = response[i].distanceInKm;
            cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.textContent = response[i].description;
        }

    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "/getRunningActivities");
    xhttp.send();

}
```

I cannot find the problem. I have the exact same code for another page and thats working properly.

Comment: Seems like a js file path problem. Can you see your js file is loaded on network tab?

Comment: There are only two possibilities: 1) `script.js` is not loaded at all. Check the request for `script.js` in the developertools. 2) there is a syntax error in `script.js` which prevents the browser from sucessfully evaluating it

Answer (score 0):

I copied your entire code exactly in my vs code, and launched it, and everything is working.

The `getActivityTables`  function worked fine.

---

But you can try to use the `addEventListener()` inside the javascript itself, it's better than the regular html events attributes.

But your code doesn't have any problems, I tried it myself.

You can capture the console and the network tab in your browser then we can figure out what's happened.

Comment: The script.js file is loaded in the network tab. Stangely these code blocks are working in new files, but not in my original file.

Comment: Really strange, but what can the reason be?!!

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `<script src="scripts.js"></script>` from the head tag And put it at the end of the Body tag

like this :

```
<body onload="getActivityTables()">    
    <div id="" class="container">
        <div class="activityDiv">
            <h1>Running Activities</h1>
            <table id="runningActivity-table" class="table">
            </table>
        </div>                
    </div>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

if problem still
in scripts.js file add :

```
window.addEventListener('load',getActivityTables())
```